# SQL count users for each product belonging to a certain account

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a relationship:

```
Product -- 1-----* -- User --* ----- 1-- Account
```

I want to list the count of user for each product belong to a certain account.

For example:

```
Product_1  User_1  Account_1
Product_1  User_2  Account_1
Product_2  User_3  Account_1
Product_3  User_3  Account_2
Product_4  NULL    NULL
```

I want the result to be:

```
Product_1 2
Product_2 1
Product_3 0
Product_4 0
```

I have an answer but unfortunately it's incorrect. Please give me a hand. Thanks.

```
SELECT p.id, COUNT(users.id)) 
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN users ON p.id = users.product_id
WHERE users.account_id = 1
GROUP BY p.id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the test on `account_id` into the `ON` condition of the `LEFT JOIN`, otherwise it turns it into an `INNER JOIN`. Try this (I'm assuming your `users` table is called `users`, it's not clear from your query as you use both `users` and `user`):

```
SELECT p.id AS product_id, count(users.id) AS num_users
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN users ON p.id = users.product_id AND users.account_id = 1
GROUP BY p.id
ORDER BY p.id
```

Answer (score 1):

Try following

```
SELECT p.id, count(CASE WHEN user.account_id = 1 THEN 1 END) FROM products p
LEFT JOIN users 
ON p.id = user.product_id
GROUP BY p.id
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's works but less performance than the other one. Cheers